# Scrapy pagination fails after page 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, scrapy

I'm creating a spider that would crawl every page here: http://web.archive.org/web/20141217173753/http://www.docstoc.com/documents/legal/ and return the card names only. As I expect, it should collect all items from the start page, then follow "Next" pagination link ('BookEnd' class) and repeat until there is no such a link.

What do I need to change to make pagination work properly?

I'm new to web scraping. I've already made this spider work by entering every page manually to `start_urls`, but I want to make it more automatic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class TypeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "types"
    start_urls = ["https://web.archive.org/web/20141217173745/http://www.docstoc.com/documents/legal"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for card1 in response.xpath("//*[@class='doc-title']"):
            text = card1.xpath(".//a/text()").extract_first()
            yield{"Title": text}
        for card2 in response.xpath("//*[@class='col-sm-10']"):
            text = card2.xpath(".//h3/text()").extract_first()
            yield{"Title": text}
        next_page = response.css("li.BookEnd > a::attr(href)").extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I expect the spider to crawl all 34 pages, but it quits after page 2 with this:

`DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://web.archive.org/web/20141217173750/http://www.docstoc.com/documents/legal/2> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)`

`dont_filter` doesn't work to me.

P.S. I'm using both xPath and CSS here just because I can't extract the pagination link with xPath – can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css selector to go to the next page, will actually go to the previous page as soon as you're not on the first page anymore. A way around this would be as follows:

```
next_page = response.css("li.BookEnd > a::attr(href)").extract()[-1]
```